# Tricky differentials problem involving continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, problem-solving

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $[0, \infty )$, differentials on $(0, \infty)$, such that $f(0)=1$ and $f'(x)> \frac{1}{2\surd (x+1)} \forall x>0$. Show that $f(x)> \surd (x+1)$.

Rolle's theorem and the mean value theorem are my only leads .

Can an expert provide Hints, tips, suggestions, to a solution?

Comment: Integrate both sides?

Comment: So $f(x)+c > \surd( x+1)$ after I integrate $f'(x)$?

Comment: Correct, but if this is for a proof in a real analysis class you'll want more detail. I can get you started with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x) = f(x) - \sqrt{x + 1}$.  Then you have $g(0) = 0$ and $g'(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$, so...

Comment: this is nice (without integration). +1

Comment: The mean value theorem (which is at the heart of the step following "so") is the main tool for getting info about a function from info about its derivative.  Using an indefinite integral is actually just the same thing in disguise, given how the proof of the FTC goes.

Comment: Well when I studied calculus i followed limit, continuity, derivative, integral approach. Hence to me any proof using derivative looks technically simpler and better than the one using integration although by FTC they are more or less equivalent under very general conditions.

Comment: Oh, it is both simpler and better, no question. :)

Answer (score 2):

To show the statement in your question is true, first prove that if $f(x)$, $g(x)$ are integrable functions on an interval $[a,b]$, with $f(x) < g(x)$, then $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx < \int_a^b g(x) \, dx$. I would do this using Riemann sums.

To apply this to your particular case, take $f'(t)$ and $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{t+1}}$ to be your functions which you know are integrable (why?). Then let $[0,x]$ be your interval.